# Proving a well known result of metric spaces without using Zorn's Lemma.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, separable-spaces, second-countable

I saw a proof of the result using Zorn's Lemma:

**Statement:** If $X$ is a metric space in which every uncountable set has a limit point,then $X$ is separable.

The proof was a bit constructive and does not seem intuitive to me.So,I want to do it without Zorn's Lemma.I was proceeding by assuming $X$ is not separable.Then I was trying to find an uncountable set which has no limit point.But I got stuck and cannot find a way out.Can someone show me a way to prove the above theorem without using Zorn's Lemma.

Comment: Just a thought, It might be impossible without using Zorn's lemma (it is equivalent to the axiom of choice, so it is VERY strong)

Comment: @JustDroppedIn I mean without **directly** applying zorn's lemma,you can apply axiom of choice.I am looking for an intuitive way rather than constructive,which may be longer than the constructive well know proof.

Comment: This is a pedantic point, but generally "constructive" mathematics excludes the axiom of choice and all equivalent statements (like Zorn's lemma). The reason for this is that one can derive the law of the excluded middle from the axiom of choice; this is [Diaconescu's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diaconescu%27s_theorem). So in particular if the proof of this theorem involves Zorn's lemma it is not "constructive" in the sense used by most mathematicians

Comment: Do you mind clarifying what you mean by "constructive" and "intuitive" proofs?

Comment: @AtticusStonestrom See a construction may be intutitive,I am looking for a proof that would seem like it could have been done by one if he can understand the underlying idea or proof sketch,but there are some proofs which involve devastating construction and you would not find as if you too could have done it like cantor's theorem.